# SQL required to display all name branches that i have but not all branches has barcode that i search

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table called [Updated_SQLSOLD] with field name [Branch], [Barcode] and now i have 10 branches but not all branch has barcode

Example.

```
*[Branch]    *[Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch5  |
  branch6  |
  branch7  |
  branch8  |  25122225
  branch9  |
  branch10 |
```

```
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode] FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] where [Barcode] = '25122225'
```

Result - - is

```
*[Branch]    *[Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch8  |  25122225

now how to display all branches even if no serial is available, like this

*[Branch]    *[Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1  |  25122225
  branch2  |  25122225
  branch3  |  25122225
  branch4  |  25122225
  branch5  |  Null
  branch6  |  Null
  branch7  |  Null
  branch8  |  25122225
  branch9  |  Null
  branch10 |  Null
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove where clause OR use UNION ALL. Use NULLIF([Barcode],''), which will convert your empty string to NULL value. ORDER BY [Branch] when use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Do not consider any condition in your select statement. Simply write :

```
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode] FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD]
```

Or if you want to have condition and also null values :

```
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode] FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] where [Barcode] = '25122225' or NULLIF([Barcode],'') is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
select Branch,
    case when Barcode = '25122225' then Barcode else 'Null' end as Barcode
from Branches
```

Comment: what if, if somethilike this i need to group by the branch                                              ``` *        [Branch]    *[Barcode]
----------------------
  branch1   |  25122225
  branch2   |  25122225
  branch3   |  25122225
  branch4   |  25122225
  branch5   |  34343434
  branch6   |  34343434
  branch7   |  56565656
  branch8   |  25122225
  branch9   |  22222222
  bra nch10 |  4444444

Comment: @rsupson If you can provide the sample data and expected results for the grouping you desire then I will try to provide you with the appropriate SQL query.

Comment: @rsupson For the data you provided in the comment just now, there is only one branch per record so grouping by branch will not give you a different result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-JOIN for your table with a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT u1.[Branch], u1.[Barcode]
FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD]  u1
LEFT JOIN [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] u2 
  ON u1.[Branch] = u2.[Branch] 
 AND u1.[Barcode] = u2.[Barcode] -- this line is optional
 AND u1.[Barcode] = 25122225 -- assuming [Barcode] is a numeric field, 
                             -- no need for quotes
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5417617a974ce672189cbbdee5d13cdb)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete. Obviously the answer to your question so far is

```
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode] FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD]
```

But I'm guessing that you have other Barcodes that you want to exclude? So is the question "where my Barcode or Barcode is null"? So:

```
SELECT [Branch], [Barcode] 
FROM [MHO_Report].[dbo].[Updated_SQLSOLD] 
where [Barcode] = '25122225' or [Barcode] is null
```

Or something else?